# React router v6 Nested Route inside component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So I have this RouterComponent with some routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" component={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/user" component={<User />} />
</Routes>
```

then in User I have something like this:

```
const User = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SomeOtherStuff />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/user" component={<SomeComp />} /> //default component in /user
        <Route path="/user/edit" component={<EditForm />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}
```

This is not working.

I know I can put all the routes in the RouterComponent but this removes the flexibility of changing only some part of the `User` component

Comment: "I know I can put all the routes in the RouterComponent but this removes the flexibility of changing only some part of the `User` component" - Not true. `User` could render an `Outlet` instead of the `Routes` and descendent routes, then the "RouterComponent" renders the nested routes. In other words, you can convert `User` to be a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes).

Comment: @DrewReese I found that I could use "*" in the path of the User Route and then inside the User Component I should match excluding the "/user" part and it works

Comment: Affirmative, that is the solution in the linked duplicate. I was just pointing out here that you *could* put all your routes in the `RouterComponent` if you wanted to and it would still work.

Comment: Also just noticed you are using a `component` prop.... RRDv6 `Route` doesn't have any `component` prop, so make sure you are using the correct `element` prop.